# Chrome extension manifest error: content_script[0].matches[0]

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I believe this might be the problem:

```
"content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches" : [
        "http://195.88.55.16"
      ],
      "js" : ["script.js"],
      "run_at" : "document_idle",
      "all_frames" : false
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append a slash (probably slash + star) to the host in the `matches` section in order to make the pattern valid.

```
  "matches" : [
    "http://195.88.55.16/*"
  ],
```

For more information, have a look at the documentation for [match patterns](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html):

> Here's the basic syntax:
>
> ```
> <url-pattern> := <scheme>://<host><path>
> <scheme> := '*' | 'http' | 'https' | 'file' | 'ftp' | 'chrome-extension'
> <host> := '*' | '*.' <any char except '/' and '*'>+
> <path> := '/' <any chars>
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that will work. My only thought is that this will make it valid for all the subpages of the site, while I want it to only run at the front page. not a huge problem though.

Comment: For just the front page, omit the trailing asterisk; just use the slash.

Comment: `"http://195.88.55.16"` bad.     `"http://195.88.55.16/"` good and front-page only.   `"http://195.88.55.16/*"` good and fires on all subpages.